# Word VBA 2010 - Formatting the last paragraph in a table cell

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a project that I export from MadCap Flare into Word 2010 and I use a VBA script to update the formatting of the document. I am trying to check the style of every paragraph in the document, then if it matches a specific style apply a multi list level format.

It almost works problem-free. The problem arises when the paragraph falls as the last paragraph in a table cell. In this case, the range includes the end of cell marker (so the range includes every paragraph of the cell) and thus the change applies to every paragraph in the table cell instead of simply the last.

The code I use is as follows:

```
For Each iPara In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
    With iPara.Range
        If iPara.Style.NameLocal = "div_NoteText" Then
            .ListFormat.ApplyListTemplateWithLevel ListTemplate:= _
            ListGalleries(wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1), _
            ContinuePreviousList:=False, ApplyTo:=wdListApplyToWholeList, _
            DefaultListBehavior:=wdWord10ListBehavior, ApplyLevel:=1
        End If
    End With
Next
```

What changes do I need to make for this to work for the last paragraph in a table cell?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Excellent question for your first!  So, if I understand you correctly, if there is a table in the middle of the document, with multiple cells, and the first cell has multiple paragraphs, you only want the last paragraph in that first cell to be modified?  But current all of the paragraphs in that cell are affected?

Comment: Thank you for the welcoming, and feedback. Perhaps some images can best describe the issue: http://imgur.com/a/TVSBX 1. Before any macro has run. 2. Macro has modified the second paragraph in the table cell correctly. 3. Macro is selecting the third paragraph in the table cell (because it includes the end of cell marker, it then highlights all paragraphs). 4. The formatting is applied, but to the whole cell. Not the desired effect.

Comment: I'm unable to view the link due to restrictions on my network, but I created a word doc with a table 2 columns wide by 3 rows, placed two paragraphs in cell(2,2) and your code treated both paragraphs separately.  If you turn on symbols `ctrl` + `shift` + `*`  Do you see multiple paragraph symbols in the cell or just one?

Comment: In cell (2,2) I have three paragraphs. Turning on the symbols, I see the paragraph marker after the first and second paragraph, but not the third. The third paragraph only shows the end of cell marker, which looks like a circle with lines coming out of it.

Comment: That's what I would expect.  I added `MsgBox iPara.Range` inside the for loop and it listed each paragraph separately, which makes me think it may have to do with your conditional of the `div_NoteText`.  Is that a built-in NameLocal or an alias?

Comment: It's simply a Word style that was created by building the word output with the following settings: Font: (Default) Arial, Italic, Indent:
    Left:  0.06"
    Right:  0.03", Left
    Line spacing:  single, Space
    Before:  5.25 pt
    After:  5.25 pt, Widow/Orphan control

Comment: When I added `MsgBox iPara.Range` in the loop, for the last paragraph in the cell it only showed that last paragraph, but it also showed a box icon on the next line in the messagebox. I think that represents the end of cell character, and when that is selected, the entire cell is actually included in the range.

Comment: Perhaps you will see how the whole cell is selected if you try `iPara.Range.Select` in the loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "end of cell" marker is Chr(13) + Chr(7), so you can detect a paragraph located at the end of a cell using code similar to below:

```
Sub Tester()
Dim EOC As String
Dim p As Paragraph
Dim rng As Range

    EOC = Chr(13) & Chr(7)

    For Each p In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs

        If Len(p.Range.Text) > Len(EOC) And p.Range.Text Like "*" & EOC Then
               Set rng = p.Range

               'commenting out next line will select the whole cell
               rng.MoveEnd wdCharacter, -1  

               rng.Select
               MsgBox "Found paragraph at end of cell..."
        End If

    Next p

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the information on the EOC. It will definitely help lead me to a solution and I will have more time to test tomorrow. Unfortunately I have had no luck with `rng.MoveEnd wdCharacter, -1` as it does not seem to deselect the EOC character in word (or even modify the range, leaving the entire cell selected when I only want the last paragraph). Similar EOC material: http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=631

Comment: In my testing (using the code I posted) it worked fine: when selecting a paragraph at the end of a table cell, only that paragraph - and nothing else in the cell - was selected.

Comment: Works as advertised. Thank you for the answer and efficient expression. I must have performed simple coding errors when testing the MoveEnd method.

Comment: This is wonderful and astonishing, and fixed my problem! Note that the chr(7) does NOT appear in the Range.Characters array, it ONLY appears in the Range.Text string. Also the Range.End-Range.Start does NOT reflect this extra chr(7).

Answer (score 1):

This program will check all paragraphs by first scanning all paragraphs that are not in a table, then checking all tables only applying changes to the last paragraph in each cell.

**CheckParagraphs**

```
Sub CheckParagraphs()

  For Each iPara In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
      With iPara.Range
          If Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) = False Then
              If iPara.Style.NameLocal = "div_NoteText" Then
                .ListFormat.ApplyListTemplateWithLevel ListTemplate:= _
                ListGalleries(wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1), _
                ContinuePreviousList:=False, ApplyTo:=wdListApplyToWholeList, _
                DefaultListBehavior:=wdWord10ListBehavior, ApplyLevel:=1
              End If
          End If
      End With
  Next

  CheckTables
End Sub
```

**CheckTables**

```
Sub CheckTables()

  Dim oPara As Range
  Dim count As Integer
  For Each t In ActiveDocument.Tables
    For Each r In t.Rows
        For Each c In r.Cells
            With c.Range
                'Only act on the last paragraph
                With .Paragraphs(.Paragraphs.count).Range
                    If .Style.NameLocal = "div_NoteText" Then
                        .ListFormat.ApplyListTemplateWithLevel ListTemplate:= _
                        ListGalleries(wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1), _
                        ContinuePreviousList:=False, ApplyTo:=wdListApplyToWholeList, _
                        DefaultListBehavior:=wdWord10ListBehavior
                        .SetListLevel Level:=1
                    End If
                End With
            End With
        Next
    Next
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I had thought about separating out the cases before as you have done here, but I still didn't know how to handle the table case. Thank you for this wonderful example, which I will work with and test out in the morning. My only concern is that `.Paragraphs(.Paragraphs.count).Range` will still contain the EOC character, which I have yet to figure out how to exclude from a range.  I have had no luck with `rng.MoveEnd wdCharacter, -1` or `myRange.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd`, neither seem to actually modify the range (and I am uncertain why). I will update after more testing tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks again for working through the problem with me. The other answer worked perfectly, as you know.

Answer (score -1):

This is how I trim my range in table in MS Word

```
Sub remove()
    Set aa = Selection.Tables(1)
    dim bb, cc as integer
    bb = Selection.Tables(1).Rows.Count
    cc = Selection.Tables(1).Columns.Count
    
    For i = 1 To bb
    For j = 1 To cc
        '1st
        Set dd = aa.Cell(i, j).Range.Paragraphs(1)
        If Len(dd) < 2 Then
        dd.Range.Delete
        End If
        
        'last
        ee = aa.Cell(i, j).Range.Paragraphs.Count
        ff = Right(aa.Cell(i, j).Range, 3)
        If Asc(ff) = 13 Or Asc(ff) = 32 Or Asc(ff) = 46 Then
        aa.Cell(i, j).Select
        Selection.Paragraphs(ee).Range.Characters.Last.Previous.Delete
        End If
    Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not clear how this answers the question which is about formatting the final paragraph within table cells. Your code appears to be deleting paragraphs / characters, not applying formatting?